# Сочетание, напоминающее известный фразеологизм

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, фразеология, как, обороты-с-как

*Я голодная. Голодная, как медведь.*

Требуется ли постановка запятой в таком определённо-личном предложении? В данном случае имеется некоторое отступление от фразеологизма "голодная как волк".

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того, что это предложение не определенно-личное. Что касается вопроса о запятой, то ее нужно поставить.

**В Полном академическом справочнике под редакцией Лопатина [о таких случаях](https://info.wikireading.ru/69111) сказано:**

Если имеются некоторые отклонения в употреблении устойчивых оборотов (порядок слов, подмена слов в устойчивых словосочетаниях и др.), то выделение возможно: *А на мосту, **как черт, черный** взметнулся плащ* (Цвет.). — ср.: *черный **как черт***; *Нити древесные... Тают, **как дым*** (Н. Матв.). — ср.: *развеялся **как дым***; при уточнении выделение обязательно: *Кто это шагает смело, **как герой**, в предрассветной темени зимнею порой* (Вл. Федоров). — Ср.: *сражался **как герой***.

Comment: Это не определённо-личное предложение, так как "голодная" подполагает третье лицо?

Comment: В определенно-личном предложении нет третьего лица.  Определённо-личные предложения — это односоставные предложения, сказуемое которых имеет форму глагола 1 или 2 лица единственного или множественного числа настоящего и будущего времени изъявительного наклонения, а также повелительного наклонения.

Comment: Ну извините — опять поправила и внесла ссылку (думаю, так читабельнее).

Comment: Римма Михайлова, я рад, что вы следите за ответами и правите их к лучшему. Спасибо.

Comment: Владимир, это не односоставное предложение, это неполное двусоставное с пропуском подлежащего (я), которое восстанавливается из контекста предыдущего предложения: Я голодная. (Я) Голодная, как медведь. Эмоциональность достигается с помощью повтора.